# Can we check the print statement of app in playstore?

Tags: flutter

I have uploaded an app in playstore but I am facing an error. Can we check the print status somehow?

[image]

This is my try catch block
I wish to see the error here somehow but my app is already in playstore. Any help?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Connect your device to your system and in your Android studio terminal type `flutter logs` and open the app it will show all print statements which you put in the app.